# BASH echo write mysql input

Tags: bash

Have a bash menu where variables write to file for mysql input.
heres what I have:

```
    echo "CREATE DATABASE '$mysqldbn';

#GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup' WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myip' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES< LOCK TABLES on '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$rip' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';" > nmysql.db


mysql -u root -p$mypass < nmysql.db
```

problem is to get variables to show I had to put them in single quotes, the single quotes show up as I want for instances like '$mysqlu'@'localhost'. But how can I remove the quotes and still get to use the variable in the instance like, CREATE DATABASE '$mysqldbn' ? Double quotes wont work either, I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see your problem here, but you may use `${mysqldbn}` to quote the variable name in bash, would that help?

Comment: Thanks thats what it needed! 

Problem was mysql wont except CREATE DATABASE 'example';

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to omit the single quotes where you don't want them.

But I would recommend using a here document. Approximately:

```
mysql -u root -p$mypass <<EOF

CREATE DATABASE $mysqldbn;

#GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup' WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$myip' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES< LOCK TABLES on '$mysqldbn'.* TO '$mysqlu'@'$rip' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlup';
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to use double quotes to display values, here's my example:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar="MyValue"
echo "$myvar"
echo '$myvar'
echo '${myvar}'
```

Generates:

```
MyValue
$myvar
${myvar}
```

Hope this helps